# How to reset an FillFactor of an index

Tags: sql, sql-server

How I can reset the Fill Factor of an index?

The index was built with this statement:

```sql
ALTER INDEX index_name ON table_name REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = '70')
```

Comment: There's an answer to a similar question on the DBA Stackexchange site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/how-can-i-set-the-index-fill-factor-back-to-server-default

Comment: ALTER INDEX is product specific. Tag the dbms used!

Comment: @jarlh thanks i add the additional Tag

Comment: I slightly edited your question to fix the grammar, and reformat the SQL statement, so you get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Fill factor only makes sense in the context of rebuild/reorg operations, so do one of those and specify the target fill factor when doing it.